How to change the documentclass(.cls) to package(.sty)[like `l3doc`]?
As the title mentioned, I have read this link and the clsguide, and I know the .cls is used for a new document class(like article, standalone or minimal); and the .sty are packages to provide additional function.
However, if my purpose is to plant some useful commands from some documentclass .cls to some package's .sty file, does there exist some general methods to convert the .cls to .sty, (or further the opposite, from .sty to .cls?)
A concrete example is the l3doc.cls, how to plant some commands in l3doc.sty like \cs or function and syntax to a package which can be used in documentclass like book? The link didn't provide a concrete methodology of the convertion.
I have a preliminary idea: I can search the targeted command like:
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment { function } { O{} +v }
  { \__codedoc_function:nnw {#1} {#2} }
  { \__codedoc_function_end: }

And serach recursively to find the definition of \__codedoc_function:nnw and \__codedoc_function_end:, until I meet some l3kernal functions or commands provided by latex2e, but it seemed not so easy.
In a word, my question could be summarized as how to convert the commands in l3doc into a non-article document, and the general methodology of the convertion.

there is no general method. all you can do is search for the command or environment you want and hope the implementation is not too deeply entangled with stuff you don't want. or make a renamed copy of the class and edit it as you wish. if you want a lot of stuff, that might be easiest.

The usual (and only general)  thing is to include package class commands into a class by doing \RequirePackage{...} That conceptually is what l3doc.cls is doing, it is doing \LoadClass[article}\RequirePackage{doc} so it's a class with doc features built in. It isn't just that it has a collection of hacks on top, but don't follow the hacks as a model

To add, thinking in terms of processes, you can start creating an "empty" package, move functions  step-by-step from the .cls to this .sty AND use this .sty in said class. Of course you need to control results won't change both for the .cls and the .sty used separately. // The overarching concepts are "refactoring" and "Test Driven Design (TDD)", which includes "testbenches". // As an alternative you can rebuild or mimick the function you'd like to see in a package, with its own (in-)compatibilites.

@cfr missing colon after "that"

In my imperfection practice, I just change the suffix name of l3doc.cls to l3doc.sty, then comment the statements on about Line402 \LoadClass{article} , and the documentclass book could use the l3doc.sty well as the normal usage show in l3doc.pdf said.

Actually thans to cfr's comment, if my target is a lot of stuff, make a renamed copy of the class and used as a package is good. However if my target is just to use some of the functions in the package, the above operation to just recopy ALL the .cls remains some deeply entangled with stuff you don't want, maybe that need my patience and time to immersed in the documentclass. Thanks All Here!

@Explorer you should really, really call it something other than l3doc.sty to avoid confusion. even if you will never share it with anybody else, you may share it with yourself in a decade's time. also, do note david's comment about not following the hacks .... (though I think this is a lost cause in truth.)

I know that the name of l3doc.sty will be something related to the namespace that cause werid problems,thanks yr warn. And with David Carlisle's comment, I'm not so clear with the conception hacks(?) As a user's perspective, I think the command provided in l3doc like \cs or \Args maybe useful in some illustration articles(NOT ALL with doc features), why there says  "It isn't just that it has a collection of hacks on top, but don't follow the hacks as a model"? @DavidCarlisle

you should just use doc.sty and add one or two user-level additional commands as needed, do not use l3doc class and in general never use commads with two underscores __ from other package code, they are explicitly internal commands not to be used from elsewhere.

For l3doc class "hacks" please check the  documentation, the title says this experimental class.  However, please note that it is by no means in final state and is \emph{likely} to undergo modifications, even \emph{incompatible ones}! Thus, using it might therefore  require you to do updates first paragraph highlights:   It is much less stable than the main expl3 packages. Use at own risk!

Yes, i know the risk for the experimental class l3doc and the internal private method \__, however I didn't search the keywords in texdoc l3doc? Is that my method wrong?
